# Asp.net partial view doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, partial-views

Main view:

```
@model BTGHRM.Models.EmployeeOverallReport
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_EmployeeMain.cshtml";
}

@foreach (var item in Model.ListOfPersonalData)
{
    Html.Partial("Partial/_EmployeeOverallReportList", item);
    <br/>
}
```

MyPartial:

```
@model BTGHRM.Models.PersonalData
@{
WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model.ListOfWorkData, canSort: false, rowsPerPage: 15);
}

@Html.Label(Model.FirstName)
@Html.Label(Model.LastName)
@Html.Label(Model.Appointment)
@Html.Label(Model.Division)

@if (Model.ListOfWorkData.Any())
{
@grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "table",
        headerStyle: "table_HeaderStyle",
        footerStyle: "table_PagerStyle",
        rowStyle: "table_RowStyle",
        alternatingRowStyle: "table_AlternatingRowStyle",
        selectedRowStyle: "table_SelectedRowStyle",
        columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("ProjectName", @Resources.Localization.project, format: @<text>
                <span class="display-mode"><label id="ProjectNameLabel">@item.ProjectName</label></span>
            </text>, style: "p60"),
            grid.Column("Activity", @Resources.Localization.activity, format: @<text>
                <span class="display-mode"><label id="ActivityLabel">@item.Activity</label></span>
            </text>, style: "p60"),
            grid.Column("ProjectEndDate", @Resources.Localization.start_date, format: @<text>
                <span class="display-mode"><label id="ProjectStartDate">@item.ProjectStartDate</label></span>
            </text>, style: "p60"),
            grid.Column("ProjectEndDate", @Resources.Localization.end_date, format: @<text>
                <span class="display-mode"><label id="ProjectEndDate">@item.ProjectEndDate</label></span>
            </text>, style: "p60")
        )
)
}
```

My models:

```
public class EmployeeOverallReport
{
    //DataBlock:
    public bool PersonalDataPartBool { get; set; }
    public List<PersonalData> ListOfPersonalData { get; set; }
    //ColumnsNeeded:
    public bool EmployeeIdBool { get; set; }
    public bool FirstNameBool { get; set; }
    public bool LastNameBool { get; set; }
    public bool AppointmentBool { get; set; }
    public bool DivisionBool { get; set; }

    //DataBlock:
    public bool WorkDataPartBool { get; set; }
    public bool ProjectWorkerIdBool { get; set; }
    public bool ProjectIdBool { get; set; }
    public bool ProjectNameBool { get; set; }
    public bool ActivityBool { get; set; }
    public bool ProjectStartDateBool { get; set; }
    public bool ProjectEndDateBool { get; set; }

}

public class PersonalData
{
    //Not all
    public List<WorkData> ListOfWorkData { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Appointment { get; set; }
    public string Division { get; set; }
    //And more
}

public class WorkData
{
    public int WorkerId { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string Activity { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? ProjectStartDate { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? ProjectEndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Bool properties are made for sorting purposes and they are not in use now. The problem is that this code returns literally nothing:

[image]

However it returns brakes and in tracing mode all models have correct data and i am able to get inside the grid with breakpoints.

Comment: before passing it to the view \ partial view what is the state of the model ?

Comment: @SimonPrice It is a model, that contains a `list of employees`, each element of employee's list has it own list of `work data`. Elements of `list of employees` are passed into partial view one by one, where web grid is built with data from `work data` list. In tracing mode model has valid data.

Btw, i just brought code from partial into a main view and it works fine.

Comment: @SimonPrice i forgot to place @ before      Html.Partial("Partial/_EmployeeOverallReportList", item);

But i dont understand why this row wasnt seen as a row of the text

Comment: glad I could be of assistance :)

Comment: @SimonPrice if you can explain why this row didnt appear as row of regular text - answer plz i ll mark as a solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Html.Partial` in your for loop is still calling the HtmlHelper for the Razor Page.  In other words, you were still calling the function, but that return value wasn't being rendered into the view. Had your loop been

```
<text>
    Html.Partial("Partial/_EmployeeOverallReportList", item);
</text>
```

Then the `Html.Partial` would have shown as text